# How to tell at runtime if you're inside of a unit test in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, runtime

Does anyone know the least hacky way of determining if Python code is being run by a unit test?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it matter?  If your function  behaves differently when you're unit-testing it, then I imagine it's not a very good unit test ;-).

Comment: That is going to be extremely hacky by the mere premise of it. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: If you want to mock out some components when unit testing, [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is the way to go. Don't detect the test and do something differently.

Comment: Guys, I'm aware this is very unusual and almost always a no-no. However, I'm in some very unusual circumstances where what I want to test is 'un-mockable', not without a huge amount of work, at least. The options are to have an imperfect test for the next several months or no tests for the next several months.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all the comments.

**Don't do this**.

Your function/class/component should **NOT** behave differently under *testing*.